# Need to reinstall OSX Mavericks on older MBP (originally with Leopard)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hdd

The HDD on my trusty Mac has given up the ghost, and an attempt at repair this weekend resulted in failure to boot. It originally had 10.5, which I updated through to Mavericks.
I still have a Snow Leopard install disk so I can at least get it running after HDD replacement, but Sierra will not run on it due to age and is the current offering in the App Store. Is there some way that I can obtain and upgrade to Mavericks to ensure my backup works?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's dozens of questions & answers on this site about this topic.  Have you searched for similar questions?  Of the answers given on those questions, which have you tried?  If they didn't work, what errors did you receive?  See [ask] for guidance on how to ask questions.